# Find the total dollar amount spent by shopper in Ubercart, using Views?

Tags: 7, views, ubercart, log-messages

I'd like to run a report that will show info about each shopper, as well as the total dollar amount they have spent on my site. I know that the "Customer Orders" page (for instance, mysite.com/admin/store/customers/orders/1 for user #1) shows the total amount spent by an individual customer... how can I access that total amount in Views so I can build a custom report?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I found that Ubercart does have this already built-in, at this URL: admin/store/customers/view. Oh well, better late than never!